# ImportError on cross import modules

Tags: python

I am quite confused about the whole cross importing in Python. I have a package with a main Module **main.py** and several sub-modules **b.py** and **c.py**, with one class in each module namely `class main`, `class b` and `class c` respectively.

In **__init__.py**:

```
from .main import main
from .b import b
from .c import c
```

in **main.py**:

```
from .b import b 
from .c import c
class main:
```

in **b.py**:

```
from .main import main 
class b:
```

will raise ImportError, to solve it we can:

```
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        from .main import main
```

This will be ok. But I don't quite understand why. And what to do if I have multiple class or methods in **b.py**. Will giving import main in each method very inefficient and even affect performance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not Java and neither requires nor even recommand using a "one module per class" scheme - quite on the contrary actually -  and does NOT support circular dependancies anyway - as you already found out. IOW, if you have two classes (or functions or anything else) depending on each other then they should obviously live in the same module (which is what the "low coupling, high cohesion" rule mandates anyway).

Importing in a function or method body is considered bad practice, will indeed add some overhead on each call (not that much overhead but in a tight loop over a huge dataset it can make quite a difference), and should really only be used as a last resort temporary Q&D hack.

> what would you recommend to make the module less cluttered as putting them in one module results in a very large file with too many lines (at least for my liking)

It's impossible to answer this without knowing what the code actually looks like, but if 3 (three !) classes are enough to reach your "too many lines" limit, then chances are your classes are doing too much and would benefit from being refactored into distinct classes (and possibly plain functions - python doesn't mandate all code to live in classes), some of which might then be extracted to other utility modules. The "single responsability" principle is a good guide here...  You might also have some code that could be rewritten in a terser (yet still readable) way - it looks like you don't have much experience with Python and chances are you're not harnessing the full language (and stdlib) power.

Now sometimes even with the best possible design and coding, you still end up with rather large modules because the domain is inherently complex and requires quite some code...  That's a fact of life and something you have to learn to live with, sorry.

Oh and yes: this all also depends on what you qualify as "too large for your liking", of course - for the record, 1000+ lines modules are quite ordinary.

Comment: thank you very much. This makes sense. However, what would you recommend to make the module less cluttered as putting them in one module results in a very large file with too lines (at least for my liking) to manage.